# The Following Java Script Function not working for jcanvas chart

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function () {
            debugger;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "RMDashboard.aspx/get_dept_pend_fin_wo",
                data: "{}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: OnSuccess,
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                }
            });
            function OnSuccess(response) {
                    //alert(response.d)                 
                var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("ccpevman", {
                    title: {
                        text: ""
                    },
                    axisX: {
                        interval: 3,
                        intervalType: "month",
                    },
                    data: [{
                        type: "spline",
                        dataPoints: [  jQuery.parseJSON(response.d) ]
                    }]
                });
                chart.render();

            }
        }
</script>
```

The web method from the cs page returns the string in the format as

{ label: "08/2015", y: 25, markerColor: "Green" },{ label: "09/2015", y: 87, markerColor: "Green" },{ label: "10/2015", y: 158, markerColor: "Green" },{ label: "11/2015", y: 180, markerColor: "Green" },{ label: "12/2015", y: 336, markerColor: "Green" },{ label: "01/2016", y: 57, markerColor: "Green" },{ label: "02/2016", y: 187, markerColor: "Green" },{ label: "03/2016", y: 341, markerColor: "Green" },{ label: "07/2015", y: 1, markerColor: "Red" },{ label: "09/2015", y: 3, markerColor: "Red" },{ label: "10/2015", y: 2, markerColor: "Red" },{ label: "11/2015", y: 1, markerColor: "Red" },{ label: "12/2015", y: 3, markerColor: "Red" },{ label: "02/2016", y: 25, markerColor: "Red" },{ label: "03/2016", y: 33, markerColor: "Red" }

I have converted this to json and applying to datapoints is there any alternative way to achive this.

Comment: That's not valid JSON.

Comment: Hello Pointy but the chart is working if i directly copy and paste the string as dataPoints:{ label: "02/2016", y: 25, markerColor: "Red" },...............................................{ label: "03/2016", y: 33, markerColor: "Red" }

Comment: It's valid JavaScript, but not valid JSON. Property names must be quoted with double quote characters in JSON, but not in JavaScript.

Comment: Have you tried doing Eval(response.d) maybe that would make a valid object.

Comment: No its not working sir(thepanch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the string to the following format::

```
var objectstring =response.d;
var objectStringArray = (new Function("return [" + objectstring+ "];")());
```

Then assigned the objectStringArray to datapoints

```
dataPoints: objectStringArray
```

It is working perfectly form me now...Thanks All